# Passing input variables to a Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: ssis

I am trying to find a way to be able to pass a couple variables into a Windows Task Scheduler task and I can't find the answer anywhere.  I'm not even sure it is possible.

The purpose of this task will be to run a batch file, which will call dtexec to run a SSIS package against my SQL server.  I need to remote execute the SSIS package and found that this could be done via PsExec on the remote server, calling a scheduled task on the SQL box.  I have gotten this method to work well on other packages.

However, I have a task which requires a StartDate and an EndDate for the package.  I can explicitly put the dates into the Add Arguments portion of the scheduled task and it runs fine.  I need this argument to be dynamic so when some one requests this data, they enter the dates, and it runs using those dates.

I'm expecting I need to put something in the Add arguments field which will allow this to happen, but I can't find the syntax anywhere.  As well, how can I set these variables via command line to set them.

I expect the command to look like 
C:\PsTools\psexec \SQLBOX schtasks /run /tn SCHEDTASKNAME /tr *input variable syntax*

Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Help me understand the goal. The desire is to run an SSIS package at a particular time or are those parameters for the package?

Comment: The goal is to execute a SSIS package on command on a remote server.  Sort of a primitive report.  I used to use DTSRUN on the remote box before moving to SQL 2k8, but as I can't install DTEXEC without having another license, I need to get around this.

Comment: What sorts of things are you doing on that server/in the package? Must the SSIS package run on that server? Is there something preventing the package from running on a licensed box that reaches out to other boxes to collect its information?

Comment: Users will be running a batch file which has a menu to select which data set they need.  Two of these data sets have date ranges which the user need to input.  These two are the ones causing the issues.  I need to have a way to pass these dates into the Scheduled Task so it passes through to the SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule the SSIS package execution you should create A SQL Server Agent JOB.
YOu will be able to pass variables values to the package using

```
SET "\Package.Variables[YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME].Value";"\"VARIABLE_VALUE\""
```

hope this help